# Botkit Slackbot responds with 401 error every time

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, slack-api, botkit

I'm trying to create a very simple Slack bot using botkit and Google App Engine, but for some reason I keep getting 401 errors any time I message the bot. The weird thing is that the Slack Event Subscription URL (the one ending in /api/messages) validates correctly, and I get a 200 response in GAE logs and validation within Slack.

But whenever I actually message the bot it always gets a 401 error with no message explaining the error at all. I've tried various combinations of the code below, and have now stripped it down to the bare minimum as found [here](https://botkit.ai/docs/v4/platforms/slack.html). Aside from dependencies and a code to decrypt credentials (which I've verified is working as expected), this is my full code at the moment:

```
botInit();

async function botInit () {

    const credentialsRaw = await getCredentials();
    const credentials = JSON.parse(credentialsRaw);
    const adapter = new SlackAdapter(credentials);
    
    const controller = new Botkit({
        adapter: adapter
    });
    
    controller.on('message', async(bot, message) => {
        await bot.reply(message, 'I heard a message!');
    });
}
```

I have also tried this for the messaging function:

```
controller.ready(() => {
    controller.hears(['hello', 'hi'], ['message', 'direct_message'],
    async (bot, message) => {
        await bot.reply(message, 'Meow. :smile_cat:')
    })
})
```

and this for setting up the controller:

```
const controller = new Botkit({
        webhook_uri: '/api/messages',
        adapter: adapter
    });
```

And everything gives back the same exact 401 error, despite all of them working with the Event Subscription URL verification on Slack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same issue but figured out the problem.

I had been using **Client Secret** as **clientSigningSecret**

But I should use **Signing Secret** !

[image]

Comment: Thanks, knew it was a stupid mistake but just didn't know what else to try!